# disable crop frame to resizable in Android

Tags: android

I am using below code to crop an image from an intent and the output image size should be 640px. Here my problem is that I have to restrict or disable the crop frame to 640 and it shouldn't be resizable.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
intent.setType("image/*");                  
intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 640);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 640);
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 640);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 640);
intent.putExtra("scale", true);
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

Comment: Have you solve you issue???I am facing same issue.Please post the answer.

Comment: @Nagendra - do you mind sharing how you did this ?

Answer (score -1):

```
public void imageGalleryCapture(){

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    // call android default gallery
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    // code for crop image
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 640);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 640);

    try {
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // Do nothing for now
    }
}
```